# jersey with wildfly 10

Tags: jboss7.x, jersey-2.0, wildfly-10

I started jersey rest services project with wildfly server. As Jboss has restEasy default implementation it does not support Jersey. I tried using jboss-deployement-structure.xml, changes in web.xml as false for restEasy, removing jaxrs subsystems in standalaone.xml. Nothing is successful.

Anyone please suggest me the solution who tried and succeeded.
Jersey version is 2.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RestEasyRemovalTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.accenture.porta</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <!-- <filter>
        <filter-name>sampleFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.accenture.porta.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sampleFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
      <subsystem name="webservices" />
      <subsystem name="resteasy" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="javaee.api" />
      <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
      <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" />
      <module name="org.jboss.as.webservices.*" />
      <module name="org.jboss.ws.*" />
    </exclusions>

    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.activation.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.el.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.enterprise.deploy.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.inject.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.resource.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.rmi.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.security.jacc.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true" />

      <!-- <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" export="true" services="export" /> -->

      <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.xml.registry.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />

      <!-- This one always goes last. -->
      <module name="javax.api" export="true" />
    </dependencies>

  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: What error do you get. Also adding your current configuration would help

Comment: Added the configurations, Could you please look into that

Comment: Are you using any Jersey specific classes or annotations? If not, why not just use RESTEasy?

Comment: Yes I am using glass fish Jersey, I can use Jersey but I am migrating from tomcat to Jboss. So I thought finding solution is better than escape.

Comment: What are you using specifically from Jersey though? Is it something special that JAX-RS does not provide?

Comment: No it is JAX-RS implementation, but Jboss has rest easy as built in module. I want to disable that and use Jersey.

Comment: Yes, but If you are using plain JAX-RS implementation, why do you want to switch to Jersey? Resteasy shoud work just fine..

Comment: As I already mentioned I am migrating from tomcat to Jboss. Code is already developed using tomcat and Jersey. I am finding a solution to use Jersey with jboss

Answer (score 0):

For people arriving here from google, you need to register your resource files as described [here](https://javasolutionsguide.blogspot.com/2017/03/howtomigratefromjersey1tojersey2InWebsphere.html)